# Why I can't insert my data ? c# winform

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, winforms

I wanna ask about this ..

My query is not successful but i didn't see anything wrong here
here's my Code :

```
        private void save_btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection("server=127.0.0.1;database=project;Uid=root;Pwd=admin");
            MySqlCommand job;
            string id_pembayaran = count_id("payment");
            string order_id = String.Concat("ORD", id_pembayaran);

            for (int i = 0; i < List_Pembelian.Rows.Count; i++){
            job = new MySqlCommand("INSERT INTO payment VALUES(@id,@ordid,@userid,@nama,@jlh,@total)", con);
            job.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id",count_id("payment"));
            job.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ordid", order_id);
            job.Parameters.AddWithValue("@userid", User_Validation_Field.Text);
            job.Parameters.AddWithValue("@nama", List_Pembelian.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value.ToString());
            job.Parameters.AddWithValue("@jlh", List_Pembelian.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value.ToString());
            job.Parameters.AddWithValue("@total",List_Pembelian.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value.ToString());
            con.Open();
            try
            {
                job.ExecuteNonQuery();
                int a = job.ExecuteNonQuery();
                MessageBox.Show(a.ToString());
                MessageBox.Show("SUKSES");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);

            }
            finally
            {
                con.Close();
            }
          }
        }
```

Did I do any mistake in my code? If yes please tell me x.x

Comment: ExecuteNonQuery returns an int representing number of row affected. Use a variable to get that result and let us know what it is. Often in these cases you are just looking at a different database than your program.

Comment: i got -1 when i try it to put it in variable x.x , i didn't understand what is that

Comment: Then it was not successful. I think MySQL requires parameters added to command in same order as in query so change that and try again.

Comment: same result , still not successfull x.x ....@Crowcoder

Comment: I don't work with MySQL, but typically I see parameters as"?" instead of "@paramName". I don't know if it matters but that's the only other thing that can be wrong with your code if you do not get an exception. Does the insert work when you try it in a query tool?

Comment: the insert is works on query tool but i dunno why i can't insert it like usual :/

Comment: post your `show create table ` output

Comment: @e4c5 : here's the link http://imgur.com/a/LC2Mi

Comment: **show create table**

Comment: @e4c5 : you mean this ? http://imgur.com/a/nqxb8

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that you want to insert in a for loop, apparently from a collection (datatable I guess) but you never use the elements in that collection since your indexes don't change in the loop. Replace them by the index i and you can loop through your collection.

Update:
You should fix the order of the parameters you pass to the query. Your parameters order does not match the order of the column you provided in the comments. Also fix the data types.

Comment: ups , sry i forgot to change that index ... :D but my problem still same my query is success but my data isn't updated

Comment: How does your table look like?

Comment: my table is like this : ID int(10) , userID varchar(10), orderID varchar(10), itemName varchar(10), itemCount int(10), totalPrice int(30)

Comment: @Wilx you should change the order. Based on what you wrote in the above comment, the order must be Id, userId, orderId, itemName, and so on.

Comment: @Wilx fix the data types. All columns but the Id expect string.

Comment: @Wilx then update the question with the latest changes.

Comment: What is `count_id("payment")` and what does it do?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131797/discussion-between-mahdi-and-wilx).

Comment: it's for counting how many row that i have in my table :/ and i already tried check there and nothing wrong on it